# Custom bodytext wrapping in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I create a new frame using this code:

In Page TSConfig:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.section_frame {
   addItems.104 = Accordion
}
```

and in setup:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
key.field = CType

default = CASE
default {
    key.field = section_frame

    # Wrapping whole CE
    104 = TEXT
    104.value = <li>|</li>

    }
}
```

Everything working fine but I need to change one more thing, and I don't know if it's possible.

I will be using this frame only for `text content element` and I need to wrap whole `bodytext` in `<div class="content">|</div>` element. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    key.field = section_frame
    104 = TEXT
    104.value = <li>|</li>
}

tt_content.text.20.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.text.20.innerWrap.cObject {
    key.field = section_frame
    104 = TEXT
    104.value = <div class="content">|</div>
}

lib.stdheader.stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject = CASE
lib.stdheader.stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject {
    key.field = section_frame
    104 = TEXT
    104.value = <div class="title">|</div>
}
```